# Will git rm -f <file> remove the file from another branch

Tags: git, git-branch, rm

I work in many branches and have pulled a file from one branch (`branchA`) to the current one (`branchB`).

I used `git checkout file.name`

I would like to remove `file.name` from branchB without modifying `branchA`. Will `git rm -f file.name` remove the file from just `branchB` or will it remove it from branchA as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, running

```
git rm -f file.name
```

does not affect *any* branch, yet. This command merely

- removes the file from your working tree, and
- *stages the removal* of `file.name` (in other words, it writes, in the index, that `file.name` should no longer be tracked.)

Then, when you create a commit, the tree object of the current branch's new tip will no longer reference `file.name`.

And because staging and committing only affect the current branch, the other branches (if any) will not be affected by this removal. If you later check another branch (to which `file.name` was committed), `file.name` will be checked out to your working tree.

Answer (score 4):

Any git operation you do will be for the current checked out branch itself.

So git add, rm , commit will only be effective for the **currently checked out** branch itself.

just make sure you do not cherry-pick the commit into another branch. In that case you may lose it :) but don't worry you can always get it back by reverting to older commit. So chill, git is your best friend

Answer (score 2):

It will only be removed from the current branch. If you check out another branch, the file will be present again.